# Can Raspberry Pi be used as a desktop virtualization server?

Tags: remote, server

I would like to use my Raspberry Pi B+ as a desktop virtualization server. Please check out the below image as reference.
[image: Desktop Virtualization]

Here,

- Desktop Virtualization Server - Raspberry Pi.

  Windows XP - My laptop or just my PC(connected over network)

Assuming that i have a RDP client on my laptop,is there a way i could use it to connect to a virtual OS(such as windows,ubuntu etc..) running on Raspberry Pi? 
Any help would be appreciated. Sitting Fingers crossed !

Comment: You have the idea here backward.  The point of doing this would be to offload work from the client to the server.  I.e., the slow little machine would be the client, the server would be the big fast one.  Otherwise it is just a bad joke.

Comment: Good point, @goldilocks. I'm working with a client that is setting up RPis as thin client machines to replace $3,500 proprietary industrial boxes. For that, the RPi is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

With only 1 GB RAM, the RPi 2B is unlikely to do be able to handle 3 virtual machines running Vista (??).

Comment: Or is there  any possiblity for any other lighter OS ? Even, getting a pair of Windows 98's to work is fine for me.

Comment: You'd have to be running an x86 emulator, since there is no version (as in none, and never will be) of windows for ARMv6 (the A/B/+) and only the IoT 10 for ARMv7 (the pi 2).  At that point, the bad joke would cease to be funny at all.   Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0GL66m5HY4) booting XP in QEMU (the x86 emulator) on an rpi -- it takes *more than 20 minutes to boot*.  Just forget about this.  It is absolutely totally completely infeasible.